# Resize the panel slowly slowly not suddenly on mouseEnter and mouseLeave event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to resize the panel slowly not suddenly on mouseEnter and on mouseLeave event.

Can someone explain how i can deal with it?

Here is my "code":

```
   <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" 
                Background="{DynamicResource MyBorderBlueGradientBrush}" 
                BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="1,1,1,0">
                            <DockPanel x:Name="pinDockPanel" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" LastChildFill="False"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Transparent">
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="pinButton" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="auto" MaxWidth="26" Height="26"
                              Background="{DynamicResource MyBorderBlueGradientBrush}" Focusable="False"
                              DockPanel.Dock="Right" Checked="pinButtonChecked" BorderThickness="0" 
                              Unchecked="pinButtonUnchecked" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyBorderBlueGradientBrush}"  FontFamily="Webdings">
                                    <Label x:Name="Pinback" Background="{DynamicResource MyBorderBlueGradientBrush}" Width="26" Height="26" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyBorderBlueGradientBrush}">
                                        <Label x:Name="Pin"  FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Content="?" Width="25" Height="25" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <Label.RenderTransform>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="16" CenterX="29" CenterY="0"></RotateTransform>
                                            </Label.RenderTransform>
                                        </Label>
                                    </Label>


                                </ToggleButton>

                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="11"
                           Foreground="White"  FontFamily="Tahoma" Text="Applications" Margin="4,0,0,0"
                                Background="Transparent" 
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Name="borderSelectedButton" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" 
                Background="{DynamicResource MyBorderBlueGradientBrush}" 
                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyBlueBorderSolidBrush}" 
                BorderThickness="0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5" Margin="1,3,1,0">
                            <DockPanel x:Name="selectedButton" Width="Auto" Height="20" >
                                <TextBlock Name="selectedButtonText" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                           FontSize="11" Foreground="{DynamicResource MyDarkBlueSolidBrush}" 
                           Text="" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontFamily="Tahoma"/>
            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <!-- / LEFT PANEL HEADER ( APPLICATION & SELECTED BUTTON )  -->
                        <!--  RELATED CONTROL SPACE For the Diagnostic Page -->
                        <ScrollViewer Name="scrolviewerRelatedButtons" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="1,0,0,0">
                            <StackPanel Name="relatedControlStackPanel"
                        Background="White" Height="auto" 
                        ClipToBounds="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>

                        <!--  RELATED CONTROL SPACE For the readerSettingButton Page -->
                        <!-- MAIN BUTTONS  -->
                        <Grid x:Name="gridMainButtons" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,1,0,1" 
                    Background="{DynamicResource MyBlueBackgroundGradientBrush}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Button Name="diagnosisButton" Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource MyBottomLeftButtonStyle}" 
                    Height="auto" Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyBlueSolidBrush2}" BorderThickness="0,0.2,0,0.2" 
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="3,1,1,1" Click="Diagnosis_Click">
                                <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               Foreground="{DynamicResource MyBlueSolidBrush2}" FontFamily="Tahoma"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="12">
                                        <Underline>D</Underline>iagnosis
                                    </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                            <Button Name="firmwareButton" Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource MyBottomLeftButtonStyle}" 
                    Height="auto" Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyBlueSolidBrush2}" BorderThickness="0,0.2,0,0.2" 
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="3,1,1,1" Width="Auto" 
                    Click="firmwareButtonClick">
                                <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               Foreground="{DynamicResource MyBlueSolidBrush2}" FontFamily="Tahoma"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="12">
                                        <Underline>F</Underline>irmware
                                    </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                            <Button Name="readerSettingButton" Grid.Row="2" Style="{DynamicResource MyBottomLeftButtonStyle}" 
                    Height="auto" Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyBlueSolidBrush2}" BorderThickness="0,0.2,0,0.2" 
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="3,1,1,1" Width="Auto" 
                    Click="readerSettingButtonClick">
                                <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               Foreground="{DynamicResource MyBlueSolidBrush2}" FontFamily="Tahoma"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="12">
                                        Reader <Underline>S</Underline>ettings
                                    </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                            </Button>


                        </Grid>
                        <!-- / MAIN BUTTONS  -->
                        <!-- HID LOGO  -->
                        <Border Grid.Row="4" Name="logoPanel" Background="{DynamicResource MyBlueBackgroundGradientBrush}" 
                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyBlueBorderSolidBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" Height="Auto">
                            <!--<StackPanel x:Name="Logo"  Width="auto" Height="32" 
                        Background="{DynamicResource MyBlueBackgroundGradientBrush}" >-->
                            <Image Source="graphics\HID_OMNIKEY.bmp" Height="auto" Width="auto" Name="HID_logo" 
                       Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                            <!--</StackPanel>--></prev>
```

**c# file**

```
    private void LeftPanelMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        private double LeftPanelMaxWidth=240;
        if (resizeFlag == false && pinFlag == false)
        {

                LeftPanel.Width = LeftPanelMaxWidth;
                mySidebarControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                borderSelectedButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                scrolviewerRelatedButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                gridMainButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                logoPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                resizeFlag = true;
                pinButton.ToolTip = Properties.Resources.TOOL_TIP_PINUP_BUTTON_UNCHECKED;
                scrolviewerRelatedButtons.Margin = new Thickness(24, 0, 0, 0);
                pinDockPanel.Margin = new Thickness(24, 0, 0, 0);
                selectedButton.Margin = new Thickness(24, 0, 0, 0);
                diagnosisButton.Margin = new Thickness(24, 0, 0, 0);
                firmwareButton.Margin = new Thickness(24, 0, 0, 0);
                readerSettingButton.Margin = new Thickness(24, 0, 0, 0);
                logoPanel.Margin = new Thickness(24, 0, 0, 0);
                mySidebarControl.myNavigationPaneButton.Background = (Brush)FindResource("MySelectedButtonOrangeGradientBrush");
                mySidebarControl.applicationborder.BorderBrush = (Brush)FindResource("MySelectedButtonOrangeGradientBrush");

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't just post code with the question in the subject and expect people to help you out too much. What have you tried, do you think something is going wrong? You obviously know what events you want to fire, so an attempt at doing it would be a good idea.

Comment: you need to tell us what is your problem and what you are doing to have an answer >> what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Basic principle:

1. Create a [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx) with a [`Trigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Trigger.aspx) on `IsMouseOver`
2. Use [`Trigger.EnterActions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.triggerbase.enteractions.aspx) and [`Trigger.ExitActions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.triggerbase.exitactions.aspx) to [start animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) which manipulate your control's size.

Alternatively you can hook up two [`EventTriggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx) (see example in documentation) for [`MouseEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter.aspx) and [`MouseLeave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave.aspx). Unless you state any particular problem this is all i have for you.

Comment: Pls get me through c# programing

Comment: I will not. Look at examples, read the [animation overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) and come back if you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following will expand and collapse the grid as you mouse in and out. The duration set on the animation will set the expand / collapse to take 1 second.

```
<Grid.Triggers>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseEnter">
    <BeginStoryboard>
      <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SomeGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" AccelerationRatio="0.5" DecelerationRatio="0.5" From="40.0" To="140.0" Duration="0:0:1" />
      </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
  </EventTrigger>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseLeave">
    <BeginStoryboard>
      <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SomeGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" AccelerationRatio="0.5" DecelerationRatio="0.5" From="140.0" To="40.0" Duration="0:0:1" />
      </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
  </EventTrigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```